# Why aren't neural networks contractions?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

I'm not sure I understand why neural networks aren't considered contractions, as Geoffrey J. Gordon says in his paper: [Stable Function Approximation in Dynamic Programming](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eggordon/ml95-stable-dp.pdf):

> "Our theorems in the following sections will be based on two views of function approximators.
>
> First, we will cast function approximators as expansion or contraction mappings; this distinction captures the essential difference between approximators that can exaggerate changes in their training values, like linear regression and neural nets, and those like k-nearest-neighbor that respond conservatively to changes in their inputs.
>
> Second, we will show that approximate temporal difference learning with some function approximators is equivalent to exact temporal difference learning for a slightly different problem.
> ...
>
> Definition: A function $f$ from a vector space $S$ to itself is a **contraction mapping** if, for all points $a$ and $b$ in $S$, $|| f (a) - f(b) || \le \gamma || a-b ||.$ Here $\gamma$, the contraction factor or modulus, is any real number in $[0,1]$. If we merely have $|| f (a) - f(b) || \le || a-b ||$, we call $f$ a nonexpansion.
>
> $\qquad$ For example, the function $f(x) = 5 + \frac{x}{2}$ is a contraction with contraction factor $\frac{1}{2}$. The identity function is a nonexpansion. All contractions are nonexpansions.

I understand that at least in practice they've been shown to greatly exaggerate differences between similar target functions, but I suppose there's a theoretical explanation for this?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "contraction" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why neural networks aren't considered contractions, as Geoffrey J. Gordon says in his paper.

[image]

I am not sure how strongly you mean *aren't considered*, if you mean it in a strong sense or weak sense.

Contraction theory is probably not very well known in the AI community, but I did find some material to suggest contraction theory is being applied to NNs.

[Perspectives on Contraction Theory and Neural Networks, Bullo 2022](http://motion.me.ucsb.edu/talks/2022-02-10-FBullo-ContractionNeuralNets-NYU.pdf)
[Learning-based Adaptive Control using Contraction Theory, Tsukamoto, 2021](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.02987.pdf)

> The use of DNNs permits real-time
> implementation of the control law and broad applicability to a
> variety of nonlinear systems with parametric and nonparametric
> uncertainties. We show using *contraction theory* that the aNCM
> ensures exponential boundedness of the distance between the
> target and controlled trajectories in the presence of parametric
> uncertainties of the model, learning errors caused by aNCM
> approximation, and external disturbances.

In the weak sense specific NNs can be considered contractions, but in *general* contractions must be [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) and it's not clear that in the strong *universally true sense* for all cases of NNs. There may be some Networks, that for some set of inputs may reveal some discontinuity.

Also function f must be a mapping of S to itself.
In image classification we are not mapping S -> S but instead are mapping R^MxNxC -> R^n  where n is the number of classes (or 1 when using integer encoding)

Its also not clear that all networks would satisfy the condition:

> || f(a) - f(b) ||
> ---------------   <= k < 1 
> || a - b ||

Suppose we had a vector a of size n of all 1's [1,1,1,...] and a vector b of all zeros of size n [0,0,0,...] then their norm || a - b || = sqrt(n)
a neural network would need to map

> a -> a'= [u,u,u,...] 
> b -> b'= [v,v,v,...] such that:
> || a'-b' ||/sqrt(n) = sqrt(n*(u-v)) = sqrt(n)*sqrt(u-v) < 1 for all n

So to summarize I would say:

1. It depends on how strongly you mean *aren't considered*
2. The AI community at large is not familiar with what a contraction mapping is so the connection isn't well developed yet.
3. It may be true on case by case basis, but not universally true.

Comment: Please, don't provide screenshots. Copy and paste the actual relevant text (and provide a reference to the original).